# SQL Server - Join only when the condition is number

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table EmployeeLeave

```
  CREATE TABLE EmployeeLeave (
  EmployeeId INT,
  LeaveType VARCHAR()
  );
```

LeaveType can have numbers as well as string.

```
  CREATE TABLE MST_LeaveReason (
  ReasonId INT,
  Reason VARCHAR()
  );

  SELECT * FROM EmployeeLeave EL
  LEFT JOIN MST_LeaveReason LR ON LR.ReasonId = EL.LeaveType
```

Above query will not work as LeaveType is not always number. I want this join to work only if the LeaveType is number. How can i implement it. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your `varchar` is only going to have a length of 1, why not use `char(1)` and save the overhead of having a "variable" length?

Comment: @Larnu: `VARCHAR()` is (fortunately?) not legal syntax. It's probably not shorthand for `VARCHAR`-with-no-length-which-is-implicitly-1 in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `try_convert()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM EmployeeLeave EL LEFT JOIN
     MST_LeaveReason LR
     ON LR.ReasonId = TRY_CONVERT(INT, EL.LeaveType);
```

You can also do this in the other direction:

```
SELECT *
FROM EmployeeLeave EL LEFT JOIN
     MST_LeaveReason LR
     ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), LR.ReasonId) = EL.LeaveType;
```

Then, work on fixing the data model.  `JOIN` keys should be of the same type.  Such conversions have a drastic affect on performance.